# WHOIS personal information for .in domains

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains, whois, cctld, tld-restrictions

I'm thinking to register a .in domain through Namecheap, but when I tried to add Whoisguard to the domain name before registering it, I ran into the error message "This domain does not support privacy protection." This makes sense, since [.in domains may not use any proxy or privacy services provided by registrars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_privacy#Privacy_forbidden). The required WHOIS information to register the domain would include first name, last name, address line, city, ZIP/postal code, country, phone number, and email address.

I would rather not put all of my identifying information online, so I was curious what domains like [linked.in](https://linked.in) do. I looked up several .in domains using [this .in WHOIS lookup tool](https://www.registry.in/whois), including [linked.in](https://linked.in), [google.co.in](https://google.co.in), [amazon.in](https://amazon.in), and some smaller personal domains I could find. I couldn't see any personal info in the WHOIS results; every query had mostly blank personal info fields and the registrant email field said "Please contact the Registrar listed above" for each domain. So, if I register a .in domain, will my personal info be available via WHOIS lookup or will it be masked like the ones I checked? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure; you would have to ask your desired registrar since different registrars mask information differently.
However, I believe that most will mask most information from public searches due to GDPR which took effect in 2018.
https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/gdpr-compliance-interim-model-08mar18-en.pdf